# Selecting rows from a data frame from combinations of lists given by another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, apply, do.call

I have a dataframe, dat:

```
dat<-data.frame(col1=rep(1:4,3),
                col2=rep(letters[24:26],4),
                col3=letters[1:12])
```

I want to filter `dat` on two different columns using ONLY the combinations given by the rows in the data frame `filter`:

```
filter<-data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=NA)
lists<-list(list("x","y"),list("y","z"),list("x","z"))
filter$col2<-lists
```

So for example, rows containing (1,x) and (1,y), would be selected, but not (1,z),(2,x), or (3,y).

I know how I would do it using a for loop:

```
#create a frame to drop results in
results<-dat[0,]
for(f in 1:nrow(filter)){
  temp_filter<-filter[f,]
  temp_dat<-dat[dat$col1==temp_filter[1,1] &
                dat$col2%in%unlist(temp_filter[1,2]),]
  results<-rbind(results,temp_dat)
}
```

Or if you prefer `dplyr` style:

```
require(dplyr)
results<-dat[0,]
for(f in 1:nrow(filter)){
  temp_filter<-filter[f,]
  temp_dat<-filter(dat,col1==temp_filter[1,1] & 
  col2%in%unlist(temp_filter[1,2])
  results<-rbind(results,temp_dat)
}
```

results should return

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    x    a
5    1    y    e
2    2    y    b
6    2    z    f
3    3    z    c
7    3    x    g
```

I would normally do the filtering using a merge, but I can't now since I have to check col2 against a list rather than a single value.  The for loop works but I figured there would be a more efficient way to do this, probably using some variation of `apply` or `do.call`.

Comment: The simplest answer is don't use that format for `filter` and employ the answers from your previous question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354932/selecting-rows-from-a-data-frame-from-combinations-of-lists

Comment: So in actuality, the lists in column 2 of  filter  are 10s of elements long, so filtering by merging wouldn't work.  I know a data frame for filter probably isn't the best solution, but I need to pair each list with a single element and simultaneously filter by that element and the paired list on different columns, which I don't believe the previous answer would allow me to do.

Comment: As shown in the answer, it's doable with a semi-join, or in fact with a simple merge like `merge(dat, unique(filter2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `tidyverse`. `dat2` is the final output. The idea is to extract the value from the list column of `filter` data frame. Convert the `filter` data frame to the format as `filter2` with the `col1` and `col2` columns having the same components in `dat` data frame. Finally, use `semi_join` to filter `dat` to create `dat2`.

By the way, `filter` is a pre-defined function in the `dplyr` package. In your example you used `dplyr` package, so it is better to avoid naming a data frame as `filter`.

```
library(tidyverse)

filter2 <- filter %>%
  mutate(col2_a = map_chr(col2, 1),
         col2_b = map_chr(col2, 2)) %>%
  select(-col2) %>%
  gather(group, col2, -col1)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  semi_join(filter2, by = c("col1", "col2")) %>%
  arrange(col1)
dat2
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    x    a
2    1    y    e
3    2    y    b
4    2    z    f
5    3    z    c
6    3    x    g
```

#### Update

Another way to prepare the `filter2` package, which does not need to know how many elements are in each list. The rest is the same as the previous solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

filter2 <- filter %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data_frame(col1 = .$col1, col2 = flatten_chr(.$col2)))

dat2 <- dat %>%
  semi_join(filter2, by = c("col1", "col2")) %>%
  arrange(col1)
```

Comment: `filter` is a pre-defined function in R's standard `stats::filter` for linear filtering, so this is a double whammy.

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for sharing this information.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great solution, but does it only work if each list in col2 of filter is 2 elements long? For the problem I'm working on, the lists actually range from 5 to 30+ elements, any ideas?

Comment: @DevrajKori Please see my update. I believe the updated solution does not need to know how many elements are in each list.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable with a straight-forward join once you get the `filter` list back to a standard `data.frame`:

```
merge(
  dat,
  with(filter, data.frame(col1=rep(col1, lengths(col2)), col2=unlist(col2)))
)

#  col1 col2 col3
#1    1    x    a
#2    1    y    e
#3    2    y    b
#4    2    z    f
#5    3    x    g
#6    3    z    c
```

Arguably, I'd do away with whatever process is creating those nested lists in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! So I was under the impression that bracket filtering using the %in% operator was more efficient than unlisting col 2 to create a 2 column dataframe and then merging, is that not the case?

Comment: @DevrajKori - I don't know for sure without running a benchmark, but I imagine the looping and checking of each `list` with `%in%` is going to be more costly than a straight merge. It's also easier to translate this type of logic to dplyr/data.table/sql/python etc etc as it is just a simple join operation.